# S3 policy to allow a user to enable / disable versioning on a specific bucket AND enable / disable static website hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

For a specific IAM user I can restrict access to a specific bucket (i.e. list, get, put, delete).

However, is there an S3 policy to allow a user to do some of the meta stuff like enable / disable versioning on a specific bucket AND enable / disable static website hosting on the same bucket?

Answer (score 0):

To control versioning, users must use the [`s3:putBucketVersioning` API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTVersioningStatus.html).

To control static website hosting, users must use the [`s3:putBucketWebsite` API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTwebsite.html).

You will need to assign these permissions to a user to allow them to control Versioning and Static Hosting Website settings.